# zsh completion for umount: limit completion to one argument

Tags: shell, zsh, autocomplete, unmounting

when I use zsh completion for the `umount` command:

```
umount /mnt/t<TAB>
```

it completes the mounted filesystem `/mnt/tmp`.

But when I accidentally press tab too many times, it tries to be too helpful, and suggests other mountpoints, which leads to nonsense completions such as:

```
umount /mnt/tmp /
```

how can I limit umount completion to one mountpoint only, so that further tabs will not add any further arguments?

I think I have located the relevant section in `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_mount`:

```
  # Completion for umount.
      local excl='-V --version -h --help'
      args=(
    '(- *)'{-h,--help}'[show help]'
    '(- *)'{-V,--version}'[show version]'
    "($excl -v --verbose)"{-v,--verbose}'[verbose mode]'
    "($excl -n --no-mtab)"{-n,--no-mtab}"[don't write /etc/mtab]"
    "($excl)-r[remount read-only on failure]"
    "($excl)-d[for loopback mount, free loop device]"
    "($excl)-i[don't call /sbin/umount.<fs> helper]"
    "($excl *)-a[unmount all file systems from /etc/mtab]"
    "($excl)-t[specify file system type]:file system type:_file_systems"
    "($excl *)-O[with -a, restrict filesystems by options]:file system option:->fsopt"
    "($excl)-f[force unmount]"
    "($excl)-l[lazy unmount]"
    '*:dev or dir:->udevordir'
      )

  _arguments -C -s "$args[@]" && ret=0
```

what do I need to modify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`_arguments`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005farguments) is a complicated beast… The part that handles non-option arguments is

```
    '*:dev or dir:->udevordir'
```

This is an instance of `*:message:action` in the manual, with `*` meaning that it applies to all non-option arguments. Replace `*` by `1`, which applies only to the first non-option argument (an instance of `n:message:action`).

```
    '1:dev or dir:->udevordir'
```

I guess zsh's completion is more liberal because `umount` accepts multiple filesystems on some platforms.

To also stop completing options after the filesystem, pass `-A "-*"` to `_arguments`, i.e. change its invocation to

```
  _arguments -C -A "-*" -s "$args[@]" && ret=0
```

Comment: thank you. But it still wants to suggest options, when I press `TAB` after the mountpoint: `umount /mnt/tmp <TAB>`, will complete to `umount /mnt/tmp -`, and list all -options. Is it possible to stop completing -options, after mountpoint has been specified ?

Comment: @MartinVegter edited